# Tkinter name "delete" not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a simple drawing programme with a button that clears the canvas by deleting all shapes on it, however i am trying to use the delete() command that is built into tkinter but when i try and run it  it says that delete is not defined.`What am I doing wrong?

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
root = Tk()

class PaintBox( Frame ):
    def __init__( self ):
        Frame.__init__( self )
        self.pack( expand = YES, fill = BOTH )
        self.master.title( "Color Draw v0.2.63.23 open closed beta (Still in Alpha) greenlight edition" )
        self.master.geometry( "600x600" )

        self.message = Label( self, text = "Drag the mouse SLOWLY to draw" )
        self.message.pack( side = TOP )

        self.myCanvas = Canvas( self )
        self.myCanvas.pack( expand = YES, fill = BOTH )
        self.bd = (2)

        self.myCanvas.bind( "<B1-Motion>", self.paint )

    def paint( self, event ):
        x1, y1 = ( event.x - 4 ), ( event.y - 4 )
        x2, y2 = ( event.x + 4 ), ( event.y + 4 )
        self.myCanvas.create_rectangle( x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = "black", tags="box")

    button = Button(root, text = "Clear", command = delete(box))
    button.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

PaintBox().mainloop()
```

Here is the full traceback @mgilson:

```
    ERROR: execution aborted

In [2]: %run C:/Users/en58522/Downloads/paintcolor.txt---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    195             else:
    196                 filename = fname
--> 197             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    198     else:
    199         def execfile(fname, *where):

C:\Users\en58522\Downloads\paintcolor.txt in <module>()
      3 root = Tk()
      4 
----> 5 class PaintBox( Frame ):
      6     def __init__( self ):
      7         Frame.__init__( self )

C:\Users\en58522\Downloads\paintcolor.txt in PaintBox()
     24         self.myCanvas.create_rectangle( x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = "black", tags="box")
     25 
---> 26     button = Button(root, text = "Clear", command = delete(box))
     27     button.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
     28 

NameError: name 'delete' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?  That is frequently helpful in tracking these things. . .

Comment: `button = Button(root, text = "Clear", command = delete(box))` -- I assume you expect `delete` to be a function in `tkinter`, but it isn't.  What do you expect `delete` to do?

Comment: @mgilson delete is a predefined function in the Canvas widget

Comment: Do you need to prefix it with the canvas object, i.e. `Canvas.delete()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some working code to get you started:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
root = Tk()

class PaintBox( Frame ):
    def __init__( self, root ):
        Frame.__init__( self, root )
        self.pack( expand = YES, fill = BOTH )
        self.master.title( "Color Draw v0.2.63.23 open closed beta (Still in Alpha) greenlight edition" )
        self.master.geometry( "600x600" )

        self.message = Label( self, text = "Drag the mouse SLOWLY to draw" )
        self.message.pack( side = TOP )

        self.myCanvas = Canvas( self )
        self.myCanvas.pack( expand = YES, fill = BOTH )
        self.bd = (2)

        self.myCanvas.bind( "<B1-Motion>", self.paint )
        button = Button(root, text = "Clear", command = self.delete)
        button.pack()


    def paint( self, event ):
        x1, y1 = ( event.x - 4 ), ( event.y - 4 )
        x2, y2 = ( event.x + 4 ), ( event.y + 4 )
        self.myCanvas.create_rectangle( x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = "black", tags="box")


    def delete(self):
        items = self.myCanvas.find_all()
        for item in items:
            self.myCanvas.delete(item)

PaintBox(root).mainloop()
```

I've tried to stay true to your original code as much as possible.

A few things to notice...

1. I `.pack` the button because using `.grid` and `.pack` in the same widget doesn't work.
2. I defined a `delete` function that clears the grid of the box that you input.  I defined it in the class's `__init__`.
3. The `command = ...` should be a function.  Your original code attempted to make a function call in the `command = ...` bit.  This is a common mistake and leads to the function being executed when you create the button and then never again.  I used a bound method because bound methods get `self` passed implicitly.